# BigQuery - Increased processing time with specific table

Tags: google-bigquery

We have executed 2 queries on 2 different pairs of tables (a few joins for retrieving updated data & stuff), same (both table and query) format and goal. The difference across the queries is a string variable contained in a REGEXP_MATCH string (Regex formulas have the same format, just different core string). The rest is exactly the same, except, of course, the contained data.

Even though the query processed almost 2GB data in 20-50 seconds on one pair of tables, the same query with a different REGEX parameter (same column) processes on the other pair of tables 250 MB in 100+ seconds (sometimes even 500 to 1000+ seconds). Both queries are executed in interactive mode, without caching the results.

What might be the cause of this and is there a fix?

**How is it possible for a smaller table to need a substantial amount of processing time in comparison with a significantly larger table, given that the queries run are basically the same?**

Sorry for the below mess, tried to make it as pretty as possible.
So, for a short briefing: the query intends to create a user funnel based on their events. The data is real-time like, so we have both updated users and events. The steps included are the following:

- Get the "done" actions - get the users from updated events that are selected by the first regex
- Get the "must not be done" actions - get users from the updated events that are selected by the second event
- Create a difference among the 2 with the help of LEFT OUTER JOIN
- Join the selected users with the USERS table (also getting the updated users)

If you need additional details, let me know. I'll try to make everything as clear as possible.

```
SELECT Count(*) as count
FROM 
    (
    SELECT final._nid as _nid
    FROM (
        -- Start of events funnel
        SELECT did.user as user
        FROM (
            -- Get updated events
            SELECT events.user as user, events.createdOn as createdOn
            FROM [shop1_events] as events
            JOIN EACH (
                SELECT session, createdOn, MAX(updatedOn) as updatedOn
                FROM [shop1_events]
                GROUP EACH BY session, createdOn) as latest_events
            ON events.session = latest_events.session AND events.createdOn = latest_events.createdOn AND events.updatedOn = latest_events.updatedOn
            -- Regex for categories (concatenated categories)
            WHERE ((REGEXP_MATCH(events.category_a , r"([\:\^]100000453[\:\^]|^100000453$|^100000453[\^\:]|[\^\:]100000453$)"))) AND events.type = 10006) as did
        -- Exclude the following events:    
        LEFT OUTER JOIN EACH (
            -- Get updated events
            SELECT events.user as user, events.createdOn as createdOn
            FROM [shop1_events] as events
            JOIN EACH (
                SELECT session, createdOn, MAX(updatedOn) as updatedOn
                FROM [shop1_events]
                GROUP EACH BY session, createdOn) as latest_events
            ON events.session = latest_events.session AND events.createdOn = latest_events.createdOn AND events.updatedOn = latest_events.updatedOn
            -- Regex for categories
            WHERE ((REGEXP_MATCH(events.category_a , r"([\:\^]100000485[\:\^]|^100000485$|^100000485[\^\:]|[\^\:]100000485$)"))) AND events.type = 10006) as step_not_0
        ON did.user = step_not_0.user
        WHERE step_not_0.user IS NULL) as funnel
    JOIN EACH (
        -- Join with users
        SELECT all._nid as _nid
        FROM [shop1_users] as all
        JOIN EACH (
            -- Get updated users
            SELECT _nid, MAX(updatedOn) as updatedOn
            FROM [shop1_users]
            GROUP EACH BY _nid) as latest
        ON all._nid = latest._nid AND all.updatedOn = latest.updatedOn
        ) as final
ON final._nid = funnel.user
GROUP EACH BY _nid) as counting;
```

Comment: Add the Query and -or at least- the Regex.

Comment: Added issue details :)

Comment: I think if the difference in the two tests is only and only the regex string. Then maybe you don't need to provide all the other information for your specific setup to get better answers. What are the two regex strings in the two seperate queries that cause the delay? I see two strings in your code but they are under the same query.

Comment: The thing is I am not sure that the regex is the problem since the tables on which the query is executed are also different.

The regexes are the following:

    `([\:\^]<category>[\:\^]|^<category>$|^<category>[\^\:]|[\^\:]<category>$)`

The <category> parameter also differs for the 2 tables.
Also, simple queries sometimes have disproportionate processing times (significantly longer time for the smaller table).

Comment: BigQuery now has a new feature called "Explanation". Run both your queries, and analyse the results using the explanation to get a better understanding of why they are differing so much. If that doesn't help, grab the job ids and post them here. Then someone from the BigQuery engineering team should be able to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps this helps:

Instead of running a regular expression, maybe you can extract the value that matters and compare it with yours:

Example:

replace this

```
REGEXP_MATCH(events.category_a , r"([\:\^]100000485[\:\^]|^100000485$|^100000485[\^\:]|[\^\:]100000485$)")))
```

for this:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(events.category_a, r"\D*(\d+)\D*", (\1)) = "100000485"
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer, but this only makes me feel that I have wrongly formulated my question.

A short rephrase of my issue:
How is it possible for a smaller table to need a substantial amount of processing time in comparison with a significantly larger table, given that the queries run are basically the same?

Comment: @AlinLacea, well, i didn't explain too much, but, regular expressions can take that much time, depending on the data processed and on the efectiveness. I'm not sure if that was the issue with your query, it was only the easiest way to give you a hint to improve it.

Answer (score 0):

The amount of data processed only tells how much data the first stage reads. However, the cost of the query might be not directly related to that. E.g. the JOIN or WHERE clauses might eliminate most records in one case due to no match, but leave records in another case. Or maybe there is some skew (specific JOIN key that occurs a lot) in one table - which causes query to run slow. There are many variables affecting performance.

What you can do - after running the query, click `Explanation` button, and examine which steps take most of the time in each case, as well as how many rows are processed at this step. These values provide deeper insight into query performance beyond just how many bytes were read from original table.

P.S. The query might also benefit from a small rewrite called filter push down:

```
    SELECT events.user as user, events.createdOn as createdOn
    FROM [shop1_events] as events
    JOIN EACH (...) as latest_events
    ON ...
    WHERE <condition-for-events-table>
```

Into

```
    SELECT events.user as user, events.createdOn as createdOn
    FROM (SELECT <fields-used> FROM [shop1_events] 
          WHERE <condition-for-events-table>) as events
    JOIN EACH (...) as latest_events
    ON ...
```